# Type theory: A path from CC to UTT

Tags: type-theory

I'm hoping for a book that will bring me up to speed with the Universal Theory of Dependent Types  (UTT) as used in Agda. My current knowledge of the field is the Calculus of Constructions (CC), from [this](https://www.amazon.com.au/Type-Theory-Formal-Proof-Introduction/dp/110703650X/) book. The style of this book was great, setting up the formal system very explicitly and properly arguing any abbreviated forms ahead of using them. I'm hoping to find that structure in the next one.

I tried reading Lou's thesis on ECC, but it assumed knowledge of Martin Lof (in particular $\Sigma$-types). Unfortunately his textbook is not available electronically. I also found [this](https://github.com/jozefg/learn-tt) list of resources, though his approach to Agda is "First learn Coq", which is a different type theory (?) and doesn't suggest anything for UTT. I'm currently lacking the background in homotopy theory to read [*the*](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) book, so I'm hoping there's something that will get me across what I need for now (ECC, UTT). I'm especially hoping for a modern electronic (navigable) format with searchable text, properly annotated/bookmarked chapters, etc.

Can anyone please help with a recommendation? Alternatively a path through the maze of papers that one could read to get from CC to UTT?

Comment: As a shameless plug (I'm one of the TAs), the [HoTTEST Summer 2022](https://uwo.ca/math/faculty/kapulkin/seminars/hottest_summer_school_2022.html) is starting in July, and we'll be teaching HoTT and Agda assuming no background knowledge. It's free and entirely online, and you should leave with (at the very least) some more familiarity with Martin-Löf type theories that will help you read the material you're interested in

Comment: That's awesome! I'll definitely come along to it, thanks